# Routing for StrongSwan to access service on same server

Tags: iptables, vpn, routing, strongswan

I'm playing around with StrongSwan as a VPN provider for a few personal projects, so I'm running it on the same server as the other things I'm doing. It's all set-up and working, however I'm having an issue accessing services (e.g. nginx) on the same server.

The following two options are present in the `ipsec.conf` file:

```
  leftfirewall=yes
  lefthostaccess=yes
```

When I can connect to the VPN I can see the necessary routing and firewall rules added as follows:

**Firewall**

```
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  169 21051 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   any     10.11.12.1           anywhere             policy match dir in pol ipsec reqid 2 proto esp
  133 34163 ACCEPT     all  --  any    eth0    anywhere             10.11.12.1           policy match dir out pol ipsec reqid 2 proto esp
```

**Route list (table 220)**

```
10.11.12.1 via [server ip] dev eth0  proto static
```

When I check the packets that are coming in and being dropped, I can see that the source IP isn't that of the VPN (i.e. the traffic isn't being routed via the VPN). I know I'm connected (from `ipsec statusall` and also by checking "what's my ip").

So the issue seems to be that the traffic isn't being routed to the VPN. Is this a server-side issue, or an issue with the device connected to the VPN? All web traffic is set to go through the VPN (which is verified by checking what IP is seen by other websites).

I have seen [this similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/843264/how-to-access-the-service-on-the-server-which-act-as-the-vpn-gateway-as-well), but the answer doesn't actually provide the correct fix as far as I can see.

---

As per **ecdsa's** suggestion, here's a bit more info and clarification.

The remote user (with public IP address A.A.A.A) connects to the VPN server (with public IP address B.B.B.B). On the same server, there is an nginx server running. The remote user can access that server from a TLD which points to B.B.B.B.

When connected to the VPN (as shown below), the user is correctly assigned an IP address from the virtual IP pool. If the user runs the following command: `curl icanhazip.com` the output is the IP address of the VPN server (B.B.B.B).

Now, when connected to the VPN, if the user tries to access the nginx server via the TLD, the packets don't seem to be routed via the VPN. So my problem is trying to get the packets destined for the same server that the VPN sits on, to be routed via the VPN.

`ipsec statusall`

```
Status of IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.3.5, Linux 4.4.0-119-generic, x86_64):
  uptime: 111 seconds, since Apr 09 12:15:11 2018
  malloc: sbrk 1642496, mmap 0, used 581936, free 1060560
  worker threads: 11 of 16 idle, 5/0/0/0 working, job queue: 0/0/0/0, scheduled: 2
  loaded plugins: charon test-vectors aes rc2 sha1 sha2 md4 md5 random nonce x509 revocation constraints pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl fips-prf gmp agent xcbc hmac gcm attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default connmark farp stroke updown eap-identity eap-sim eap-sim-pcsc eap-aka eap-aka-3gpp2 eap-simaka-pseudonym eap-simaka-reauth eap-md5 eap-gtc eap-mschapv2 eap-dynamic eap-radius eap-tls eap-ttls eap-peap eap-tnc xauth-generic xauth-eap xauth-pam xauth-noauth tnc-tnccs tnccs-20 tnccs-11 tnccs-dynamic dhcp lookip error-notify certexpire led addrblock unity
Virtual IP pools (size/online/offline):
  10.11.12.0/24: 254/1/0
Listening IP addresses:
  SERVER_IP
Connections:
   ikev2-vpn:  %any...%any  IKEv2, dpddelay=300s
   ikev2-vpn:   local:  [vpn.TLD.co.uk] uses public key authentication
   ikev2-vpn:    cert:  "CN=vpn.TLD.co.uk"
   ikev2-vpn:   remote: uses EAP_MSCHAPV2 authentication with EAP identity '%any'
   ikev2-vpn:   child:  0.0.0.0/0 === dynamic TUNNEL, dpdaction=clear
Security Associations (1 up, 0 connecting):
   ikev2-vpn[1]: ESTABLISHED 4 seconds ago, SERVER_IP[vpn.TLD.co.uk]...REMOTE_IP[vpn.TLD.co.uk]
   ikev2-vpn[1]: Remote EAP identity: USER
   ikev2-vpn[1]: IKEv2 SPIs: 38003da03964bd2d_i 83715a1671973e21_r*, rekeying disabled
   ikev2-vpn[1]: IKE proposal: AES_GCM_16_256/PRF_HMAC_SHA2_256/ECP_521
   ikev2-vpn{1}:  INSTALLED, TUNNEL, reqid 1, ESP in UDP SPIs: c6f1750a_i 00b2ead4_o
   ikev2-vpn{1}:  AES_GCM_16_256, 174 bytes_i (3 pkts, 2s ago), 502 bytes_o (3 pkts, 2s ago), rekeying disabled
   ikev2-vpn{1}:   0.0.0.0/0 === 10.11.12.1/32
```

Connection Log:

```
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 11[NET] received packet: from REMOTE_IP[627] to SERVER_IP[500] (300 bytes)
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 11[ENC] parsed IKE_SA_INIT request 0 [ SA KE No N(REDIR_SUP) N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) ]
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 11[IKE] REMOTE_IP is initiating an IKE_SA
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 11[IKE] remote host is behind NAT
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 11[ENC] generating IKE_SA_INIT response 0 [ SA KE No N(NATD_S_IP) N(NATD_D_IP) N(FRAG_SUP) N(MULT_AUTH) ]
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 11[NET] sending packet: from SERVER_IP[500] to REMOTE_IP[627] (316 bytes)
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 13[NET] received packet: from REMOTE_IP[19603] to SERVER_IP[4500] (352 bytes)
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 13[ENC] unknown attribute type (25)
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 13[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH request 1 [ IDi N(INIT_CONTACT) N(MOBIKE_SUP) IDr CPRQ(ADDR DHCP DNS MASK ADDR6 DHCP6 DNS6 (25)) N(ESP_TFC_PAD_N) N(NON_FIRST_FRAG) SA TSi TSr N(EAP_ONLY) ]
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 13[IKE] initiating EAP_IDENTITY method (id 0x00)
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 13[IKE] received ESP_TFC_PADDING_NOT_SUPPORTED, not using ESPv3 TFC padding
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 13[IKE] peer supports MOBIKE
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 13[IKE] authentication of 'vpn.TLD.co.uk' (myself) with RSA signature successful
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 13[IKE] sending end entity cert "CN=vpn.TLD.co.uk"
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 13[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ IDr CERT AUTH EAP/REQ/ID ]
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 13[ENC] splitting IKE message with length of 2415 bytes into 5 fragments
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 13[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ EF(1/5) ]
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 13[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ EF(2/5) ]
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 13[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ EF(3/5) ]
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 13[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ EF(4/5) ]
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 13[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ EF(5/5) ]
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 13[NET] sending packet: from SERVER_IP[4500] to REMOTE_IP[19603] (544 bytes)
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: message repeated 3 times: [ 13[NET] sending packet: from SERVER_IP[4500] to REMOTE_IP[19603] (544 bytes)]
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 13[NET] sending packet: from SERVER_IP[4500] to REMOTE_IP[19603] (487 bytes)
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 12[NET] received packet: from REMOTE_IP[19603] to SERVER_IP[4500] (80 bytes)
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 12[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH request 2 [ EAP/RES/ID ]
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 12[IKE] received EAP identity 'USER'
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 12[IKE] initiating EAP_MSCHAPV2 method (id 0x10)
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 12[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 2 [ EAP/REQ/MSCHAPV2 ]
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 12[NET] sending packet: from SERVER_IP[4500] to REMOTE_IP[19603] (97 bytes)
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 14[NET] received packet: from REMOTE_IP[19603] to SERVER_IP[4500] (128 bytes)
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 14[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH request 3 [ EAP/RES/MSCHAPV2 ]
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 14[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 3 [ EAP/REQ/MSCHAPV2 ]
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 14[NET] sending packet: from SERVER_IP[4500] to REMOTE_IP[19603] (134 bytes)
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 15[NET] received packet: from REMOTE_IP[19603] to SERVER_IP[4500] (72 bytes)
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 15[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH request 4 [ EAP/RES/MSCHAPV2 ]
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 15[IKE] EAP method EAP_MSCHAPV2 succeeded, MSK established
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 15[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 4 [ EAP/SUCC ]
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 15[NET] sending packet: from SERVER_IP[4500] to REMOTE_IP[19603] (65 bytes)
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 16[NET] received packet: from REMOTE_IP[19603] to SERVER_IP[4500] (104 bytes)
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 16[ENC] parsed IKE_AUTH request 5 [ AUTH ]
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 16[IKE] authentication of 'vpn.TLD.co.uk' with EAP successful
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 16[IKE] authentication of 'vpn.TLD.co.uk' (myself) with EAP
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 16[IKE] IKE_SA ikev2-vpn[2] established between SERVER_IP[vpn.TLD.co.uk]...REMOTE_IP[vpn.TLD.co.uk]
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 16[IKE] peer requested virtual IP %any
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 16[IKE] assigning virtual IP 10.11.12.1 to peer 'USER'
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 16[IKE] peer requested virtual IP %any6
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 16[IKE] no virtual IP found for %any6 requested by 'USER'
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 16[IKE] CHILD_SA ikev2-vpn{2} established with SPIs cebf4aaa_i 00674f97_o and TS 0.0.0.0/0 === 10.11.12.1/32
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr kernel: [ 2641.863504] audit: type=1400 audit(1523278740.562:21): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="/usr/lib/ipsec/charon" name="/proc/3338/fd/" pid=3338 comm="charon" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr vpn: + vpn.TLD.co.uk 10.11.12.1/32 == REMOTE_IP -- SERVER_IP == 0.0.0.0/0
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 16[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 5 [ AUTH CPRP(ADDR DNS DNS) SA TSi TSr N(MOBIKE_SUP) N(ADD_4_ADDR) ]
Apr  9 12:59:00 mmstr charon: 16[NET] sending packet: from SERVER_IP[4500] to REMOTE_IP[19603] (233 bytes)
```

This is the dropped packet

```
Apr  9 13:04:12 mmstr kernel: [ 2953.930182] IPTables-Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=*** SRC=REMOTE_IP DST=SERVER_IP LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=53 ID=41666 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=5578 DPT=443 WINDOW=29200 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

The important thing to note is that the packet source is the original IP of the remote user (i.e. A.A.A.A).

This is the firewall config `iptables -L`

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  10.11.12.1           anywhere             policy match dir in pol ipsec reqid 2 proto esp
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 12 name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
           all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW recent: SET name: DEFAULT side: source mask: 255.255.255.255
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state INVALID
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:isakmp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:ipsec-nat-t
LOGGING    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
LOGGING    tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  10.11.12.1           anywhere             policy match dir in pol ipsec reqid 2 proto esp
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.11.12.1           policy match dir out pol ipsec reqid 2 proto esp
ACCEPT     all  --  10.11.12.0/24        anywhere             policy match dir in pol ipsec proto esp
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.11.12.0/24        policy match dir out pol ipsec proto esp
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             10.11.12.1           policy match dir out pol ipsec reqid 2 proto esp

Chain LOGGING (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 2/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "IPTables-Dropped: "
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: Those two options and the firewall rules they create are not relevant with an ACCEPT default policy, and the FORWARD chain is not used for local traffic (check the INPUT chain for that). Your description after the routing table output is not very clear. It might help if you posted the actual `ipsec statusall` output, logs, tcpdump output, firewall configs, firewall logs etc. to illustrate what packets are dropped and what you actually expected.

Comment: Question updated with additional information. My issue seems to be that requests destined for a web server that shares the same IP (and host) as the VPN do not get routed via the VPN.

Comment: What client do you use? It's possible that it "whitelists" the VPN server IP (e.g. with a direct route) so that IKE and ESP packets are not sent via VPN.

Comment: It's an iPhone 6 running iOS 10.3.3

Comment: OK, then it's probably not that easy to find out what it does exactly. But it's definitely possible that it e.g. uses a specific route to the server's IP to prevent IKE traffic from getting processed by the VPN (which, with 0.0.0.0/0, covers all remote IPs including the server's). But since routes are not protocol/port specific, such a route will also cover any other traffic to the same IP, which will, therefore, also bypass the VPN.